# Redux dispatch object meaning

Tags: redux, vuex

I'm new to redux, and my task is to convert this redux actions into vuex.

Now, I just stumbled upon this block of code which seems to not have any context.

```
dispatch({
    type: 'CONNECT_TO_NETWORK',
    payload: userProfile[0],
    type: 'Meta',
})
```

What does this mean?

and if anyone knows, what is the equivalent of that code into `vuex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that object  type, is the unique identifier that is going to match one of the switch cases in your reducers, payload is just a convention with redux, is going to be the other parameters or additional info you need to change the state of the app

https://www.merixstudio.com/blog/vuex-vs-redux/

Answer (score 1):

dispatch tells redux store "data changed!" with "action"(in the code above, the action is "CONNECT_TO_NETWORK") and then dispatch gives new data to the store. The store updates the data. After that, all components which uses the updated state data re-renders.